# Android: how to implement a listener for cell handovers?

Tags: android, android-intent, cellid

I need to implement code that logs whenever the current cell of the mobile network changes. It cannot run as a (background) service and it cannot routinely do checks for a changed cell id. What I need is a intent filter that fires up every time the current cell changes.

Is this possible? I tried to do this using intent filters listening for

```
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO
```

but I get nothing, even though I have set the proper permissions...

Am I doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PhoneStateListener to listen to cell location change.

```
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
```

It requires android permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
            Log.d("PhoneStateListener", "Cell Location changed");
        }
    };
```